# Efficient divisibility check for printing progress

Tags: python, modulo

In my program, when I feel it takes for a long time, I implement a progress check: I print the current value of iterator and time difference each n iterations, using the modulo of 0 (`if i % n == 0...`) .

Does the Python interpreter (or any other programming language compiler) efficiently check the divisbility for powers of 2? As in taking the last (power) bits and check if all are equal to 0?

Comment: I can assure you a single modulus operation is not the bottleneck in your program. Try to only worry about performance if and when it is an issue.

Comment: Also, that's not the modulo operator in Python

Comment: Keep in mind that checking the modulo is plenty fast. Printing is usually very slow

Comment: Especially in Python, "I feel" is not a good basis for finding the cause of poor performance. Have you tried using a profiler?

Comment: I think the OP just wants some indication of progress, rather than trying to find a way to speed up the loop.

Comment: For all the comments, I am not asking Python-specific question. More like the opposite way; if something is memory/low-level inefficient, Python does not mind it since it is slow in general. I am asking whether the progress check will be significantly more efficient for powers of 2 (since multiplication, division or even powers optimize around this - e.g. a*=9 can be written as a+=a<<3)

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency of any integer operation in Python is going to be questionable at best. Besides interpreter overhead, you also contend with the fact that integers are variable-precision, requiring more processing for each operation.

That being said, you can use bit-twiddling to check for divisibility by a power of 2. For a given `n`, you can do

```
p = (1 <<  n) - 1 # n of your choice
...
if not i & p:
    ...
```

This makes `p` into a pre- computed mask of `n` one bits. The bitwise `&` operator checks if and of the lowest `n` birs are set.

Comment: That seems to be *slower*. I did a timeit and it took about 73 ns while `not i % m` took about 55 ns.

Comment: @HeapOverflow. I am not surprised. The bottle-neck for int operations is the loop that steps over the infinite-precision integer data, not the operations themselves, usually.

Comment: Did you get the time in ns as an arithmetic mean? Measuring in ns seems to be more of a measurement error.

Comment: @Ferazhu I'm not doing anything unusual. I ran for example `python -m timeit -s "i = 1000; p = 4095" "not i & p"`, which reported `5000000 loops, best of 5: 71.4 nsec per loop`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not sure what you mean with that, but `python -m timeit "for i in range(10**6): pass"` says 31 msec while `python -m timeit -s "p = 4095" "for i in range(10**6): not i & p"` says 92 msec. So the loop/stepping appears to *not* be the bottle-neck in this case.

Comment: @HeapOverflow. What I mean is that *in* the operation `i & p`, a loop occurs under the hood to step through the buffer that contains the integer data. The overhead of that loop is likely more expensive than the machine level `&` operation undertaken at each iteration.

Comment: Ah, *that* loop. But then I find it even more surprising that `%` is so much faster than `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the formatted bytecode of the following lambdas, there doesn't seem to be any difference at the bytecode level in CPython:

```
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: dis.dis(lambda x: x % 3 == 0)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              4 BINARY_MODULO
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

In [3]: dis.dis(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_MODULO
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

In [4]:
```

The BINARY_MODULO (a modulo operation taking 2 parameters, thus "binary") is eventually processed (for 2 integers, AKA "longs") in CPython by the `long_mod` function in `Objects/longobject.c`.

From skimming through the code, it seems there are some initial optimizations for cases where the operands have only a single digit.

When they don't, `x_divrem` eventually gets called which contains the following comment:

```
/* We follow Knuth [The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 2 (3rd
       edn.), section 4.3.1, Algorithm D], except that we don't explicitly
       handle the special case when the initial estimate q for a quotient
       digit is >= PyLong_BASE: the max value for q is PyLong_BASE+1, and
       that won't overflow a digit. */
```

I don't really want to invest time in understanding the algorithm from the code (and I don't have the book mentioned), but from skimming over it - it looks like it's performing some clever bit shift operations. My bet is that in the cases where the divisor is a power of two - this algorithm will run faster. Not entirely sure though.

You can check it out here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eb8ac57af26c4eb96a8230eba7492ce5ceef7886/Objects/longobject.c#L2712